# netbeans background color

Tags: netbeans, background, color-scheme

(I want this just so I can browse my files easily instead of just walls of text)

I am using Netbeans 7 and I want to know: can I mark functions/classes or blocks with a background color?

Example: I want to make the background of a function called `getDate()` green, then I can see only that block with a green background:

```
// this block appears with a green background
function getDate() {
}


// this block appears with a red background
function setDate() {
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You can colorize all functions but not each separately. Perhaps you can request the ability to individually color editor folds as a feature

Answer (score 3):

I think you can change the background-color of all functions, but not for one in particular

How would you manage that anyway? By function name or signature?

Comment: something like i select a block of code and choose a background-color, then the color would stay there even if i reopen the project or close the ide

Comment: There are many questions involved in this. What if you refactor the function or move it to another file? I doupt that netbeans is able to keep track of that.

Comment: how can this "answer" be upvoted twice? now im gonna lose half the bounty (my rep) to someone just posting a question that adds nothing to the problem itself. i never gonna make a bount again.